# How to rotate HTML5 page on mobile rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

hi i'm trying to rotate html page on mobile so i have a div that take all the width and the height of the screen and inside the div an image so when the page is re-sized the image is re-sized to (in responsive way) my css:

```
body, html {    
  height: 100%;
}

body {
 background-color: #1E4922;
}

div#cont {
  height: 100%;
}

img#menu {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Card Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css">
</head>
<body>      
   <div id="cont">
        <img id="menu" src="static/images/2%20main%20menu.jpg"/>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the result was good when i re-size the page the image is re-sized to but now when i open this page in mobile i need to display in landscape view always so i try to do this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 768px)" href="portrait.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-device-width: 1024px)" href="landscape.css" />
```

like in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755799/creating-landscape-and-portrait-layout-using-html-and-css) and i the `landscape.css` i put this:

```
body, html {    
  height: 100%;
}

body {
 background-color: #1E4922;
}

div#cont {
  height: 100%;
}

img#menu {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
div#cont {

    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

and in the `portrait.css`

```
    body, html {    
  height: 100%;
}

body {
 background-color: #1E4922;
}

div#cont {
  height: 100%;
}

img#menu {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

form [link](http://www.html-seminar.de/css3-transform-rotate.htm) but it is not working so any help and many thanks.

Comment: Uh, you do not need to use CSS to rotate the page. Let the phone handle that. If the site is responsive, it will adjust width to fit. Using rotation would cause your text (and all other aspects of the site) to be sideways...

Comment: ok but i need it to be always in landscape view if it open from mobiles

Comment: Although I would recommend against it, you can show a message telling the user to rotate their device if they are in portrait mode. This is usually only done in HTML5 games or something of that nature. Don't make your website only viewable in one orientation. Sure, it may look better in one orientation over another, but don't force the users to do one or the other...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Javascript Detecting device orientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation)

```
function callback(){
  alert(window.orientation);
  if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
    /* some code */
  }
}

window.addEventListener('orientationchange', callback, true);
```

or [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

```
/* portrait */
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    /* some code */
}
/* landscape */
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    /*  some code */
}
```

or using HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="landscape.css" media="screen and (orientation: landscape)">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portrait.css" media="screen and (orientation: portrait)">
```